# Flutter , Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, build

[image]

**i dont understand whats wrong, yesterday i could debug the app**

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: [Resolved here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70729765/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-could-not-resolv/70730904#comment125041056_70730904) Follow the link and switch to mavenCenteral.

Comment: thanks, server started responding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70729765/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-could-not-resolv)