# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**Flutter project stopped building today all of a sudden.**

Here's the full error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Problems reading data from Binary store in /private/var/folders/_5/q7ql37gj5k7f37d865zhzl8c0000gn/T/gradle18017070233811730283.bin offset 35036 exists? true

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             29.7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried:

`flutter clean`, deleted `pubspec.lock` and `flutter pub cache repair` to get rid of cache and reinstall packages but nothing.

`flutter downgrade`, got the same error.

Fresh reinstall of flutter, same thing.

Fresh `git clone` of the project, nothing.

Any hints?

Here's my `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale
    en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/gracielacarrillo/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (4 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/gracielacarrillo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.32.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 11
      (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)              • chrome        • web-javascript • Google
      Chrome 97.0.4692.71

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Did you run: flutter pub get? If yes, open the android module of the project in Android Studio and sync Gradle.

Comment: @VarunKumar I did. Just went to sync Gradle and got this: `Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project`. I've disabled offline mode but still getting the same error.

I can see Bintray is down: https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/maven-metadata.xml

Any workarounds? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure offline mode is inactive. If the icon is highlighted it is active. If inactive, then upgrade the Gradle version in the project structure.

Comment: @VarunKumar Thanks, same error though. It's offline and it's still trying giving me : `Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project`. I've disabled offline and restarted android studio. Nothing. Updated to 7.3.3 Gradle Version, Android Gradle Plugin Version is 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are getting errors because of jcenter. Follow the link and switch to mavenCenteral.

[Switch to Maven Central](https://onesignal.com/blog/android-migrate-jcenter-to-maven-central/)

Comment: I switches to mavenCentral, upgraded to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'`. After that, I got a "Manifest merger failed targeting Android 12" error, which I solved with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67654506/manifest-merger-failed-targeting-android-12

And is now finally running. You're a star mate. Thanks!